# jQuery unwrapping wildcard selector and keep content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('div.jsn-bootstrap3').removeClass('jsn-bootstrap3').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.className.replace('jsn-bootstrap3', '')) == ''
}).contents().unwrap();
```

I use the above to detect if there is a class `jsn-bootstrap3` it will unwrap the child content and delete the div with that class but what I have in my next example is a div with multiple classes all starting with `col-`

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

I think that id I use `$('[class*="col-"]')` it would find the above div but how would I be able to delete it and just keep its content?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

Would become

```
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
```

Comment: I don't see the point of removing the class if you'll delete the element anyway. Just get contents then unwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply the same logic to your `[class*="col-"]` selector as you have to your other selector:

```js
$('[class*="col-"]').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

Comment: The OP used `.contents()` in the question, which includes text nodes. Wouldn't your answer, using `.children()`, lose those?